# Eclipse Neon w/ Tomcat 9 (new Servlet) HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm new and following a HelloWorld project in Eclipse that just added a servlet (I'm using Eclipse Neon w/ Tomcat 9).  When I run on server, I get the below errors.  There is not any issues connecting to index.html, just the servlet!  Below are screen shots, let me know if I need to provide more info -Thx

```
404Error[1]
servlet[2]
webxml[3]
indexhtml[4]
```

Comment: What is the URL that results in that 404?

Comment: Post the `web.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the web container can't find your servlet.

A web container is the component of a web server that interacts with Java servlets.

- A web container is responsible for managing the lifecycle of servlets.
- Mapping a URL to a particular servlet.
- Ensuring that the URL requester has the correct access-rights.

You can configure your servlet in web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>servletName</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>packageName.servletName</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>servletName</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/yourServletUrl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or you can use annotations since servlets 3.0.

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(name = "servletName", urlPatterns = { "/yourServletUrl" })
public class servletName extends HttpServlet {
```

It is easier and more readable.

Your url should be

```
localhost:8080/YourProjectName/YourServletUrl
```

Also i have some memories that Eclipse Neon don't work very well with JavaEE, try to download other version.

Type download Eclipse for JavaEE developers in google and try again.